# Why does the configuration of .NET Core options not work with a generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, appsettings

I have a .NET Core WebApi project. To read the appsettings in an easy way, I configure the options to be injected with DI. This works fine. However if I try to call `Configure<>()` with a generic type parameter, I get an error.

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action'

The method overloads apart from `Configure<T>(Action<T> configureOptions)` seem not to be available anymore.

**Why does the call not work with generic type parameters?**

Startup.cs

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // services.AddMvc() etc...

        services.AddOptions();

        // Works fine
        services.Configure<MyOption>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOption)));
    }

    private void AddOption<T>(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Wont work
        services.Configure<T>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(T)));
        services.Configure<T>(Configuration.GetSection(""));
    }
}
```

MyOption.cs

```cs
public class MyOption
{
    public bool MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json

```json
{
    "MyOption": {
        "MyProp": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what does `services.Configure<Foo>(GetFoo())` give you that `services.Configure(GetFoo())` doesn't?

Comment: Side note for nameof. nameof(T) is evaluated at compile time. So you would not get the desired output. You need something like typeof which is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @IgorCova Yes, I did.

Comment: @DavidG there's no overload `services.Configure()`.

Comment: I only have a `Type` can't use the generic one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change your function `AddOption` like that:

```
private void AddOption<T>(IServiceCollection services) where T : class 
{
    services.Configure<T>(Configuration.GetSection(typeof(T).Name));
}
```

you forgot about `where T : class` in the method declaration

And after you can use this method like there:

```
AddOption<MyOption>(services);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I suggest using C# style for the braces (cannot edit myself because it changes too few characters).

Comment: @Emaco The brace at the end of the line is the ancient K&R C standard, from Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie's book The C Programming Language

Comment: This may be true, but C# is not C ([C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)). After all, it was just a suggestion :)

Comment: @Emaro Thanks, I'll keep it in mind. But here it is a matter of habit and specialization written in the development team. I used this style in all projects. I'm used to it =)

Answer (score 13):

You need to use services.Configure as below:

```
services.Configure<MyOption>(setting =>
{  
    Configuration.GetSection("MyOption").Bind(setting);  
});
```

Comment: Whoever voted down - why? This is exactly the right method to use. There is no method accepting `IConfigurable` anymore as mentioned in the question. [Here](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/) you can find more info

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, `nameof(T)` would simply return the string "T".

You need to use `typeof(T).Name` instead:

```
services.Configure<T>(Configuration.GetSection(typeof(T).Name));
```

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof)

Comment: This is a helpful tip, it doesn't solve the problem though.

Answer (score -17):

If you want to become a good programmer, then learn to read errors and rummage through the documentations and implementations of libraries, and not write for every reason here. @igor-cova has already given you the right answer. The next time, be careful because writing this question took much more time and effort than you yourself would have looked into the implementation of the Configure method. Good luck
Regards, Andrew

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the input. I *read* the error message, which is why I was confused in the first place.